# How to optimise a complicated mysql query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

When I EXPLIAN this:

```
EXPLIAN SELECT m.*,m.id AS mid FROM movie_category mc 
LEFT JOIN movie m ON m.id=mc.movie_id  
RIGHT JOIN movie_area ma ON ma.movie_id=mc.movie_id 
LEFT JOIN area a ON a.id=ma.area_id 
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id=mc.category_id 
WHERE 1 and ma.area_id>0 
GROUP BY mid  
ORDER BY m.read_count desc  LIMIT 0,36;
```

I got this result:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys   | key      | key_len | ref                  | rows  | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ma    | NULL       | ALL    | NULL            | NULL     | NULL    | NULL                 | 15545 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mc    | NULL       | ref    | movie_id        | movie_id | 5       | flask.ma.movie_id    |     2 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,year_id | PRIMARY  | 4       | flask.ma.movie_id    |     1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY  | 4       | flask.ma.area_id     |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY         | PRIMARY  | 4       | flask.mc.category_id |     1 |   100.00 | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+-----------------+----------+---------+----------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

How to optimise this query? I really down't know what to do, help me out.

edit:
From the explain result,first line's Extra is "Using temporary; Using filesort",is not good.And second line's Extra and third line's Extra are all NULL, are also not good.

ps:
The query span 0.91 seconds,is very bad.How to add index to prove the query speed.

Comment: Your query makes no sense and it is not clear what you try to do there. You should really give some sample data and the expected results. I guess you could try `select * from movie m where exists (select 1 from movie_area ma where ma.movie_id = m.id and ma.area_id > 0) order by m.read_count` (and an index on `read_count`). It's not completely equivalent in special cases, but I doubt that for these cases, you want to get the result you are currently getting anyway (or designed your query in such a way to get exactly those result in these cases).

Comment: @Solarflare I was trying to query the movies from five tables, it looks like "http://dotadytt.com/movie/".The five tables include 'movie','category','area','movie_area','movie_category'.

Comment: "I was trying to query the movies from five tables" does not clarify anything. That was actually the only thing that *was* clear: you *were* trying to write a query - just the result you want to get is unclear. (E.g.:  if you `left join` a table you don't include in the `select`, then `group by` m.id, it's as if you don't join at all - that's why my query is so much shorter). You would have to specify sample data (inlcuding table definitions) and the expected output. But you should probably simply play a little bit with your data to get some experience with sql. And start easy (e.g. 1 join).

Comment: @Solarflare The result  i expected was correct, but the query was a little slowly, so i performed an "explian" cause i wanted to optimise the query, i wanted to speed up the query.

Comment: EXPLIAN isn't even a word.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

**Improve schema**

Without seeing the schemas involved, I will assume you have two many-to-many mapping table (mc, ma) that are inefficiently defined.

Follow the rules [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) ; you will gain some efficiency.

**Get rid of unnecessary tables**

`category` and `movie_category` are not really used in the query, so remove them from the query.

I assume this is a "generated" query?  Then make the generation a little more sophisticated!